# How to check a condition before starting NextJS app?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a NextJS (version 13.2.4) project. Whenever I want to run the app, I execute the following:

```
npm run dev
```

However, there is a requirement that I need to check whether a certain condition is met to allow the app to start; otherwise, exit the app before starting it.

The condition is just to check if a file exists in the machine that is running it.

How to achieve such flow?

Answer (score 0):

modify package.json file, locate the "scripts" section and find the "start" script.

and add condition statement

```
start": "if [ -f /actualpathtofile ]; then next dev; else exit 1; fi
```

you can modify condition statement as per your needs.